# Problems with overriding order grid block

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, sales-order

I want to override Magento block Order_Grid, but Magento don't recognize my class.

**/app/etc/modules/Octo_OrderGrid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Octo_OrderGrid>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Octo_OrderGrid>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Octo/OrderGrid/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Octo_OrderGrid>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Octo_OrderGrid>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>Octo_OrderGrid_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Octo/OrderGrid/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php**

```
class Octo_OrderGrid_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    //Some code
}
```

This are my three files, I followed instructions on some questions I found on this site, step by step, but again I couldn't make it work.

I can override when I put php file in /app/code/local/Mage/... but that is not what I want.

I use Magento 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Try this below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Octo_OrderGrid>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Octo_OrderGrid>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <ordergrid>
        <class>Octo_OrderGrid_Helper</class>
      </ordergrid>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <ordergrid>
        <class>Octo_OrderGrid_Block</class>
      </ordergrid>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>Octo_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

You are missing this inside blocks. You are not defining the block class name.

```
<ordergrid>
        <class>Octo_OrderGrid_Block</class>
      </ordergrid>
```

Now create a file named Grid.php inside this path `app\code\local\Octo\OrderGrid\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order` And put the below code there.

```
<?php
class Octo_OrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
}
```

Comment: don't work :( I don't even get any errors, just nothing happens

Comment: Have you changed the block file path?

Comment: yes, I changed file path

Comment: Try to add an echo and exit inside the block class and check if the execution goes inside that.

Comment: tried, nothing happens, it doesn't even read that page :(

Comment: Try clearing the var/cache. Because you did some xml changes.

Comment: Also block path is `app/code/local/Octo/OrderGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php` not this one `/app/code/local/Octo/OrderGrid/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`.